# Flask deployment on bluehost

Tags: python, python-2.7, deployment, flask, bluehost

I am facing problem while deploying flask application on bluehost server.
I made a newdomain.maindomain.com subdomain, and later did the following:

SSHed to the "newdomain" folder

created virtualenv and installed flask

created a file called   "passenger_wsgi.py"

```
import sys,os
INTERP = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'],'medsathome.freedatametric.com','bin','python')
if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP,INTERP,*sys.argv)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello Passenger'
```

now when I go to the link, I dont see Hello Passenger being printed on screen.
What is wrong?

Comment: From what you've described, you haven't done enough to actually deploy your application. Creating this file is not enough. First, you haven't described what will be running this file. [Some googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=bluehost+flask) shows you would also need an `.htaccess` file to run a .fcgi file which actually will be the python script that runs your Flask site.

Comment: Hi, I did the steps in the following documentation <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/cgi/> and changed my passenger_wsgi.py to another simple "Hello World" printing file, still i get the error of 500

Comment: Unfortunately, your saying "I followed all of the instructions and it still is not working" does not give us enough information needed to determine the problem. It is often the case that you made a mistake somewhere, or the instructions don't work with your version of a specific piece of software, etc. It would be better if you tried to understand how the various pieces of software can provide you logs that give you specific errors. Without you first trying to look at log files to find the exact nature of the problem, we can't help you.